# How to pass the ID of an object from a form to an action in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an ASP.NET MVC project with entities based on EF6 (model first). So my entities are all auto-generated for me. I have an entity, `Site` and I just want the user to select a `Site` before proceeding. I have tried a couple of ways, all of them work, but they seem very messy and unnecessary.

I was curious about the *cleanest* way to create a `DropdownList` of `Site`s, then get the selected site when the form is submitted (by `Id` or whatever other mechanism is better).

Currently I have:

The index where the user is asked to select a site:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.Sites = new SelectList(db.Sites.ToList(), "Id", "Name");
    return View();
}
```

The view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SetSite", "Home"))
{
    @Html.Label("sites", "Site:");
    @Html.DropDownList("Sites", null, new { @class = "selectpicker" });

    <div style="width:100%;height:25px"></div>
    <button class="btn btn-default" style="width:100%">Go</button>
}
```

And the `SetSite` action, where the form is submitted

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SetSite()
{
    if (Request.Form["Sites"] != null)
    {
        Session["Site"] = db.Sites.Find(Request.Form["Sites"]);
        return RedirectToAction("Home");
    }
    else
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
}
```

A few problems arise from this method. First, I really wanted to take advantage of the `@model` functionality in razor and point it towards my `Site` class, but since it's auto-generated, I don't want to go poking around and adding a whole bunch of view properties. (beggars can't be choosers?)

Second, the `Request.Form['Sites']` returns a string, and converting it to and int is ugly as hell.

As I mentioned, I'd like to use the `@model` functionality with `Html.DropDownListFor`. Is that possible when working with a list of `Sites` from the DB?

How can I get this done cleanly?

Comment: Why don't you use a ViewModel?

Comment: @HamidMosalla I'm not using a view model because when I look at the auto-generated views created by visual studio, they are able to do what I am trying to achieve by using the model-first classes. In other words, VS was able to use just one class, `Site`, to generate views for CRUD. So why can't I generate a view for choosing a site the same way? I'd like to avoid creating extra classes if I can and also continue the same design patters as the scaffolding.

Comment: There is not need to use Request.Form for this simple CRUD operation. Go with the @model and follow MVC (Model-View-Controller) structure

Comment: @UbiquitousDevelopers I agree with you entirely. My question is, *how do I do that*. I tried defining a model and creating a `DropDownListFor` but I can't seem to figure out how to create the `DroDownListFor` properly, using a model.

Comment: Never use a data model in your view when editing data - [What is ViewModel in MVC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1:-**
Controller:-

```
private List<Country> GetCountries()
        {
            var list = new Entity.Result<List<Entity.Country>>();
            list = _context.Countries.Select(tc => new Entity.Country
            {
                Id = tc.Id,
                Name = tc.Name,
                IsdCode = tc.Code,
            }).ToList();
            return list.Data.Select(x => new Country
            {
                id = x.Id,
                Name = x.Name,
            }).ToList();
        }
```

HttpGet Method:-

```
 public ActionResult Add(int id)
            {

                try
                {

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
                finally
                {
                    ViewBag.countryList = GetCountries();

                }
                return View()
            }
```

View Method:-

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.countryId, new SelectList(ViewBag.countryList, "id", "Name"), KahandasDhanji.Common.Localization.Application.Resources.ddlCountry,
                                    new { @id = "ddlCountry", @rows = 1 })
```

In Http Post Form Submitimg u handle that model value in HTTPPOST Method.

**Solution 2:-**
FormCollection class we can capture the form's values within the controller.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add(FormCollection form)
{           
  string strDDLValue = form["Sites"].ToString();

  return View(MV);
}
```

Hope Its Work !!!

Comment: Thank you for your solution! I am trying to implement it. In Solution 2, what do I do if the form value is supposed to be an `int`. Do I have to `Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["Id"])`? This is ugly to me. Is there a better way?

Comment: there no other way either u can use fromcollection or create viewmodel to handle form data...

Answer (score 1):

You can use a ViewModel to avoid converting the string value from `Request.Form`. Below is how your ViewModel class should look like

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public MyViewModel()
    {
        this.DropdownItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
    }

    public int SelectedSiteId { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> DropdownItems { get; set; }
}
```

Change the get action method in your controller as below

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<Site> sites = db.Sites.ToList();

    MyViewModel model = new MyViewModel();

    foreach(var site in sites)
    {
        model.DropdownItems.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = site.Name, Value = site.ID.ToString() });
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

Add `@model MyViewModel` at the first line in your view code and use `Html.DropDownListFor` method to generate the dropdownlist

```
@model MyViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("SetSite", "Home"))
{
    @Html.Label("SelectedSiteId", "Site:");
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedSiteId, Model.DropdownItems, new { @class = "selectpicker" })
    <div style="width:100%;height:25px"></div>
    <button class="btn btn-default" style="width:100%">Go</button>
}
```

The post action method in your controller should look like below. `model.SelectedSiteId` will be the selected value of the dropdownlist and the type is `int` so you won't have to do any conversion such as `Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form['Sites'])`.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SetSite(MyViewModel model)
{
    Session["Site"] = model.SelectedSiteId;
    return RedirectToAction("Home");
}
```